# Why do I need to rebuild registry over and over again?

Tags: drush

A while back I moved a module from the /sites/all/modules/contrib directory to /sites/all/modules/patched  It was no surprise I had to rebuild the registry (using [registry rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild)) after that so it would recognize the new location.

I pushed these changes to production, rebuilt the registry there, and all has been well ever since.

HOWEVER, every time I sync the database from production down to my local dev environment, I have to run `drush rr` (rebuild registry) again.  I even completely emptied the database (drush sql-drop) on my local box, re-synced...and STILL have to rebuild the registry after every sync.

Any idea what's going on? Where is this registry data being stored/cached on my local box and how do I fix it for good?

Comment: Are you sure the code is the same in both locations?  Make sure that you only have one copy of your module in dev, and that it is in the right location.

Comment: Good thought, but dev is a clone of prod...but I just double checked (just to be sure) and modules are the same in both locations.   As a note, another developer on the team is having the same issue on his machine, so it's not specific to my machine.